# firebase google sign in result code is always 0

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I wanted to integrate google sign In in my app using firebase and I followed all the instructions from **enabling google sign In in my firebase console and adding SHA-1 certificate fingerprint and adding the google-services.json file in the app directory.**
But whenever I am trying to sign In after selecting the google account the response code is coming out be **0** always and hence unable to sign In.

Here is the Code:-

```
    class SignInActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
    private lateinit var auth:FirebaseAuth
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in)

        val gso= GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso)
        signInButton.setOnClickListener {
            resultLauncher.launch(googleSignInClient.signInIntent)
        }
    }
    private var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){result->
        Log.i("resultCode",result.resultCode.toString())
        val intent=result.data
        Log.i("intentData",intent.toString())
        if(result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            Log.i("resultCode","reachedHere")
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent)
            handleSignInResult(task)
        }
        else{
            Log.i("unsuccessfulSignIN",result.resultCode.toString())
        }
    }
    private fun handleSignInResult(task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>?) {
        try{
            val account= task?.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
            Log.i("account","firebaseAuthWithGoogle:"+account.id)
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)

        }catch (e : ApiException){
            Log.i(ContentValues.TAG, "Google sign in failed", e)
        }

    }
    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
        signInButton.visibility= View.GONE
        progressBar.visibility= View.VISIBLE
        val credential= GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken,null)
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val auth=auth.signInWithCredential(credential).await()
            val firebaseUser=auth.user
            Log.i("user",firebaseUser.toString())
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                updateUI(firebaseUser)
            }

        }

    }
    private fun updateUI(firebaseUser: FirebaseUser?) {
        if(firebaseUser != null)
        {
            val intent= Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            Log.i("intent","Intent Started")
//            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Sign In Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            finish()
        }
        else{
            signInButton.visibility= View.VISIBLE
            progressBar.visibility=View.GONE
            Toast.makeText(this,"Sign In failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the **logcat** ( I have highlighted the result code that I logged)

[image]

I am very new to android development and this my first time working with **firebase**

Comment: I have created a [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp) in which I have implemented Firebase Authentication using a Google account. Might solve your problem.

Comment: Google the phrase "googlesigninclient kotlin resultcode 0". I found several results that should help you.